# r ggplot2 barplot groups labels don't stack

Tags: r, ggplot2

With this [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/188tKVtJ4tlwNMgE1WiVde5oQHyV5gUUD/view?usp=sharing), the following code in R (ggplot2):

```
vars <- read.csv(file="c:/R/rr.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
str(vars)

ggplot(vars , aes(x=B, y=ï..A,  group = C, fill = C))+
geom_bar(stat="identity", show.legend = F, position=position_stack(0.5)) +
geom_text(aes(label=ï..A), position = position_stack(0.5))+
xlab("year") + ylab("Total")
```

Produces this plot:
[Barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSsZz.jpg)
How do I sum values that came from the same category, e.g., 500 and 500 are from the same category, I think they should add up to show 1000 in the bar.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your dataset: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Edited my question according to your commentary.

Comment: Instead of providing a link to your full dataset host on a google drive, it is better practice to provide a small reproducible example of your dataset as code lines that can be easily copy/paste for every users and will stay on SO. Something like the output of `dput(head(df,20))` will have been enough for users to understand your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum values of the variable A for each combination of variables B and C in order to have one values per category per x label.

To do that, you can use `dplyr` package and its functions `group_by` and `summarise` as follow:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% group_by(B,C) %>% summarise(SumA = sum(A)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = B, y = SumA, fill = C))+
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE)+
  geom_text(aes(label = SumA), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

---

**EDIT: Adding total sum on top of each bar**

You can create two new dataframes, one for the sum of A in function of B and C and one for the sum of A in function of B and used each of them as follow:

```r
df_sumA <- df %>% group_by(B,C) %>% summarise(SumA = sum(A))
df_SumTotal <- df %>% group_by(B) %>% summarise(SumTotal = sum(A))

ggplot(df_sumA, aes(x = as.factor(B), y = SumA, fill = C))+
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE)+
  geom_text(aes(label = SumA), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  geom_text(inherit.aes = FALSE, data = df_SumTotal, 
            aes(x = as.factor(B),y = SumTotal, label = SumTotal), vjust = -1, color = "red")+
  ylim(0,max(df_SumTotal$SumTotal+50))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: It works! Could you please show how would be the code to write a total sum on top of each bar?

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I tried to do it by myself, but I failed. How can I sort/order your second graph? I'm using aes(x = reorder())

Comment: Sorry, what did you try to order. If you want to order your bargraph, it's a different question.

Comment: I just replaced 2 lines, fourth and eighth, with 
"ggplot(df_sumA, aes(x = reorder(B,SumA), y = SumA, fill = C))+" and
"aes(x = x = reorder(B,SumA),y = SumTotal, label = SumTotal), vjust = -1, color = "red")+", respectively.

Comment: Keep only the first part. The second part won't work because `df_SumTotal` does not have variables `SumA`. Only pass `ggplot(df_sumA, aes(x = reorder(B,SumA) ... ` . Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: Professor. Is there a way to both parts? I mean exactly as in the example above, but orderer by the total (red numbers).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to get. Please post a new question describing carefully what you are trying to get and providing a reproducible example of your dataset

Comment: After several tries, I managed to do it! I needed to use `ggplot(df_sumA, aes(x = reorder(B,SumA, sum) ... `. Notice the `sum`.

Comment: Glad you figure it out the solution to your issue. Not sure the logic behind your solution but if it works. Great !